# request discord support: Response [403]

Tags: python, request

I want to send a ticket to support.discord.com using request, but it gives me 403 code, I can't find what am I doing wrong

```
import requests

payload = {
    "utf8": "✓",
    "request[ticket_form_id]": "",
    "request[anonymous_requester_email]": "Test",
    "request[custom_fields]": "",
    "request[subject]": "Test",
    "request[description]": "Test",
    "request[description_mimetype]": "text/plain",
    "authenticity_token": ""
}




post = requests.post("https://support.discord.com/hc/tr/requests", json=payload)

print(post)
```

I want to send a ticket to support.discord.com using request, but it gives me 403 code, I can't find what am I doing wrong

Comment: Discord does not support calling their ticket API manually. Can I know what you are trying to achieve using this API?

Comment: I'm not actually aiming for anything, I was just wondering.

Comment: It can be many reasons. malformed request or security implications. Examples are CSRF tokens, authenticity tokens, and request signings or some WAF rules.